# Android XML Preview - "The following classes could not be found"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, preview

Im trying to use Material library: [Material](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary); but when i add a Button (from library) the Xml preview from Android Studio (1.2.1.1) keeps returning me the error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>    Tip: Try to build the project.

I already did Build, Clean, Restart Android Studio, change preview API on XML editor, and nothing seems to work.

On build.grade i modified this in order to add the library:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
  compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

Other info:

```
minSDK = 16
targetSDK=21
compileSDK=21
gradle Version = 1.2.3
```

test_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f">

<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What else can i do for this error from XML preview go away? The application runs without any error but i can't preview the button on XML preview window.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Mostly I suppose you are using gradle 1.2.2 
Try using gradle 1.2.3 or downgrade to 1.2.1.

Comment: @siris_cac actually i had gradle version 1.2.3, tried to downgrade to 1.2.1 but nothing changed. Any other solutions?

Comment: Please share the code of layout where you adding the button.

Comment: Im using simple layout, simplest case. Check my edited question @AnandSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is facing the same problem this is the way i managed to solve the problem:

> downgrade Android Studio 1.2.1.1 to 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f">

<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
            android:id="@+id/buttonflat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your code you are using

> compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'

Library but you are not using its code style. Please refer https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary for more information.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. Im not sure, but i guess i only need to define xmlns:materialdesign if i want to use the ButtonFlat properties (not the default from Android Button).

Comment: "<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button" is not default button. Here you are using button of navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary library. So you must have to define that.

Comment: Button, ButtonFlat, ..., Checkbox, Switch. They all give the same error: "The following classes could not be found"

Comment: You are using "https://github.com/rey5137/material" library or "https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary" library?

Comment: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary (the link from my post was wrong)

Comment: Restart you Android Studio and re-build your project. The above code should work.

Comment: I have created a new project, only to reproduce this problem. I did restart the Android Studio; Clean Project; Rebuild Project. Nothing changed.
i also noticed that if go to XML editor and "Cmd + click" on top of "ButtonRectangle", im being redirected for the ButtonRectangle.class, so he understands which component am i using, and where is its class

Comment: Upload the new project to git and share the link. Let me check it. I will do my best to help you.

Comment: I have the exact same problem using this other library: https://github.com/rey5137/material

Comment: If you use https://github.com/rey5137/material , don't forget to add maven repository. You can view [Getting Started](https://github.com/rey5137/material#getting-started) section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app > Right Click on it > Open Module Settings>Change build tool version to 22.0.1
I hope it works for you

Comment: thanks for the comment. But it doesnt solve my problem.